# Managing Android Studio dependencies

Tags: android-studio

I have a few issues:

1. When I want to add 'Google dependency' I can simply open project
   dependencies and choose proper library dependency, but this is not
   working for all 3rd party libraries (ex. Retrofit). So I have to go
   to their website copy URL and figure out the required version and
   combine proper URL- it would be nice to have some kind of auto
   completion here, to make this process faster.
2. Is there a simple way  to check for newer versions? Ex. I have 10
   dependencies in my project and I would like to know if some of them
   should be updated (I know I may update versions automatically, but I
   don't always want  this)

Comment: Be careful about your last question. Requests for recommendations on 3rd party libs are  off-topic here. I'd edit that out.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio highlights outdated dependencies in your app build.gradle file. If you mouse over the highlighted dependency, it will tell you the newest version.

To update the dependency, just replace the current version (e.g. 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0') with the new version (e.g. 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'